# python not working in home directory of ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu

When I am trying to open python interpreter in my home directory it is showing error given below but I can run python in other folder without any problem. Could you please help me resolve this problem.

In home directory:

```
suvo:~$ python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/suvo/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 62, in <module>
    import os
  File "/home/suvo/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 400, in <module>
    import UserDict
  File "/home/suvo/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 116, in <module>
    import _abcoll
  File "/home/suvo/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/_abcoll.py", line 11, in <module>
    from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
  File "abc.py", line 1, in <module>
    import openpyxl
ImportError: No module named openpyxl
```

In other folder:

```
suvo:test$ python
Python 2.7.11 |Anaconda 2.5.0 (64-bit)| (default, Dec  6 2015, 18:08:32) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
>>>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a file named `abc.py` in your home directory and Python is trying to use that instead of the `abc` module. Your `abc.py` references a module that's not installed.

Solution: don't name your scripts the same name as another module, especially one that is required by Python (well, in this case, Anaconda).